# Open owner form when a form is closed

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two forms, formA calls formB using showDialog then formA will close. Then what I want to happen is when I close formB, formA will open again also using showDialog. Any form can open formB and I want it to open the one who called it when I click a button. It's like when formA opened formB, formA will close and formB will open then when I click "done" button, formA will open again and formB will close. If formC called formB then formC will open again when I click "done" button. I tried using owner and parent properties but it wont work. Any helps will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're making things more complicated than they have to be. There's no reason to close the parent form and then reopen it, unless you have some very specific reason for wanting to do that.

Instead, hide the parent form, show the child as a modal dialog, and then show the parent form again when the child closes (and control returns to the parent):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
    new FormB().ShowDialog();
    this.Show();
}
```

Comment: @equinox If this Grant Winney's answer solves your problem you should mark it as the answer to your question so that it gets off of the unanswered question list.